# "O alface" ou "a alface"?

Tags: gênero

Escuto geralmente pronunciarem *"a alface"*. No entanto também já ouvi a pronúncia *"o alface"*. Qual destes é o correto ou mais correto?

Comment: Nunca tinha ouvido *o alface*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A forma correta é "A alface":

> A forma correta de escrita da palavra é a [alface](http://www.dicio.com.br/alface/), porque a palavra alface é um substantivo feminino.
>   [...]
>   A dúvida acerca do gênero da palavra alface surge visto a palavra terminar na vogal e, não havendo vogal que marque o feminino (a) ou o masculino (o). Existem, no português, muitas palavras terminadas em –e que apresentam a mesma forma no masculino e no feminino, como o cliente/a cliente, o agente/a agente, o estudante/a estudante,… Contudo, esta regra não se aplica à palavra alface, nem a muitas outras palavras da língua portuguesa, que têm um gênero definido: a mascote, o doce, a face, o lance,…

Fonte: [Dicio, o Dicionário Online de Português](http://duvidas.dicio.com.br/o-alface-ou-a-alface/)

Comment: [Confirmado pelo VOLP](http://www.academia.org.br/sistema_busca_palavras_portuguesas/volta_voca_org.asp?palavra=alface).